# How to know current status of recording device?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, devices

I have a device that records the audio and video using `ffmpeg`. And I am using Ubuntu 12.04 for that device, but I want to find out if the device is currently recording or if it is in idle state from command line.

Is there any Ubuntu command to find the current status of device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `lsof -t /dev/video0`.

It will return the process which owns the webcam (the first webcam should default to `/dev/video0` but if you have more then one you may have a `/dev/video1`, `/dev/video2` and so on).

On **idle** I got nothing:

```
$ lsof -t /dev/video0
```

If I start a Google Hangout for example:

```
$ lsof -t /dev/video0
4051
```